# is it possible to submit windows phone 7.5 app now that Windows Phone 8 is available

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

I developed and submitted an app which was targeted to support Windows 7.5.

The app was tested against the targeted OS (7.5) and functioned as expected under the supported OS.

The app was developed and submitted for certification just prior to the release of Windows Phone 8.

I received  certification feedback from Microsoft indicating certification did not pass because they tested it against an unsupported OS  (Windows Phone 8 device).

My question is: Is it possible to submit an app which only supports Windows Phone 7.5 to the Windows Phone store now that Windows Phone 8 is available? If so, how should I specify the supported OS in the app submission form?

Answer (score 1):

According to Microsoft, all the existing Windows phone 7.5 apps seamlessly works on Windows Phone 8. So, I don't see any point why your app is rejected for Windows phone 8, when it works properly on Windows phone 7.5.

I suggest you to check the complete details in the feedback mail, why the app is rejected. I guess there are or other reasons for the rejection of the app.

Also, install the Windows phone 8 SDK and test it yourself, whether its working on WP8 or not.

Comment: Hi,Thanks for the feedback. The feedback I received from Microsoft is that the app did not run on Windows 8 devices.The app was tested against the targeted OS (7.5) and functioned as expected under the supported OS and was not intended to run under Windows Phone 8 (At the time of development, the Windows Phone 8 framework was not even available)

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar situation where they just deactivated visibility in the WP8-store (which was what I wanted).
You may have success by writing something like the lack of support for WP8 into the certification-notes box on the right.

I found out, that WP7-apps using the maps run very poorly under WP8.